# Modbus Time storing and retrival

Tags: node.js, modbus, modbus-tcp

I'm currently working on Modbus real-time data transmission in node JS.

How date-time information handling in Modbus registers. Anyhow, Modbus holding registers able to keep 2 bytes of data and in the simulator, we are entering values in integers. Assume some real-time values will be updated on Modbus registers, My program will read the bytes of raw data & convert the date-time information.

can you provide any example conversion?

Comment: There is no standard for date or time in Modbus. If you are working on your own device that means you can do whatever you want. The most efficient seems to be the POSIX. There is even an ISO standard that defines lots of formats, it's 8601.

Comment: Thanks, @MarcosG. Right! UNIX timestamp conversation is efficient. Another quick doubt, how to handle an effective TCP connection? In my case, I need to read certain register values on every x interval.

Comment: Difficult to say not knowing anything about your setup. Do you have a real-time OS?

Comment: Okay, Understood. I don't have an actual setup right now. currently working through similartor.